# How to get values of reactive form inputs in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular-services, angular-reactive-forms

I need to grab reactive form inputs `email` and `password` and pass them to my function which calls register service method to register new user in firebase using email. Unfortunately, in chrome console after form submission I get `RegisterComponent.html:2 ERROR ReferenceError: email is not defined`

My code looks like this now:

register.component.ts

```
export class RegisterComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.form = fb.group({
  email:['',Validators.required ],
  password:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,
    PasswordValidator.cannotContainSpace])]
    })
    email = this.form.controls['email'].value;
    password = this.form.controls['password'].value;
   }


   signInWithEmail() {
     this.authService.regUser(this.email, this.password);
   }
}
```

my AuthService file:

```
 regUser() {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
 .catch(function(error) {
   // Handle Errors here.
   var errorCode = error.code;
   var errorMessage = error.message;
   // ...
 });
console.log(this.form.controls['email'].value);
    }
```

It's just part of my code that relates to the question. I'm not including register form as it's big and messy so I don't think you need to see it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

register.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="signInWithEmail()">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
       <div *ngIf="form.controls.email.touched
        && !form.controls.email.valid" class="alert alert-danger">
            Email is required
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password">
    <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.touched && form.controls.password.errors">
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors.invalidLogin"
class="alert alert-danger">
            Email or password is invalid.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors.required"
class="alert alert-danger">
            Password is required.
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors.cannotContainSpace"
class="alert alert-danger">
            Password cannot contain space.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>

</form>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Add your class in a https://stackblitz.com in order to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get value of your reactive form by using following:

```
signInWithEmail() {
     const formValue = this.form.value;
     this.authService.regUser(formValue.email, formValue.password);
}
```

BTW, i think you should adjust your `regUser` method parameter inside your service to make it take these both parameter:

Your service

```
regUser(email, pass) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
 .catch(function(error) {
   // Handle Errors here.
   var errorCode = error.code;
   var errorMessage = error.message;
   // ...
 });
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Getting same error `formValue is not defined`. Updated to your code and changed `regUser` in auth service to take the same parameters `formValue.email` and `formValue.password`

Comment: Updated OP with register component template

Comment: Where does your prorgamm throw an error? ...Your `regUser() {` should take two paramaters

Comment: I just made a SS of error. My auth service looks like this `regUser() {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(formValue.email, formValue.password)`

Comment: No..You cannot pass formValue into your service directly..I edited my post...you should change your `regUser()` to `regUser(email, pass)` ..then `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)`..

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the different place and didn't see that regUser had no parameters. It's late and I overlooked it. Works fine now.